# How can I "dual-boot" both Windows XP and Windows 7 from a partitioned hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, bootloader

I have a 750 GB hard drive that is partitioned into C and D drives. I am running XP Professional. I will be installing Windows 7. Can I install different operating systems on different drives? XP-c and Windows 7 on d?....What is dual booting?

Comment: Dual Boot is when you have two operating systems installed on a single computer. You choose which operating system on startup through a menu.

Comment: Here is where ou can find an answer to tthis:  https://superuser.com/questions/896060/what-is-the-function-of-c-boot/1251608#1251608

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely install Windows 7 on D:\ and have Windows XP on C:. Windows 7 will take care of booting into any of the 2 operating systems. The Windows 7 **[bootloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootloader)** will recognize XP and will give you an option to boot into either XP or Windows 7 (that's what dual booting is).

Comment: I'd recommend installing XP first, then the W7 installation will deal with the dual booting. Installing XP last can be problematic.