# How do I install win 7 to dual boot with xp which is already installed on my new computer?

Tags: windows-7

I am building a new computer and have already installed XP Pro on drive 1 partition 1. Drive 1 is a 500 gig SATA with 4 partitions (1 = 50 gig, 2 = 50 gig, 3 =200 gig, 4 = 200 gig).

Drive 2 is a 160 gig SATA with 2 patitions (1 = 60 Gig, 2 = 100 gig).

I would like to install win 7 on drive 2, partition 1 to dual boot with xp on drive 1, partition 1.

As XP is already installed where wanted, is there anything I should know about installing win 7 on drive 2, partition 1 ?

Thanks for any and all inputs.

Rustee

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I "dual-boot" both Windows XP and Windows 7 from a partitioned hard drive?](http://superuser.com/questions/44782/how-can-i-dual-boot-both-windows-xp-and-windows-7-from-a-partitioned-hard-drive)

Comment: close.  the [possible duplicate](http://superuser.com/questions/44782/how-can-i-dual-boot-both-windows-xp-and-windows-7) only considers installing to a single drive.  i believe win7's bootloader will install itself to the primary drive's boot sector, but not the secondary drive -- this would be a concern if you removed the primary drive, for example.  (i could be wrong; i haven't had the pleasure of playing with win7 yet.)

Answer (score 2):

If all the partitions are already set up then go ahead with the install and make sure you select the correct partition at the appropriate stage.

Win 7 installer should detect Windows XP and include it automatically in the boot menu.

Comment: Thank you Shevek, I thought that was right, but I'd rather be sure sooner than later ...  :)